# Splash screen broken?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, plymouth

I have Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, and I recently installed ubuntu-gnome-desktop. However, upon boot, the splash screen does not show, instead showing the verbose boot. I have tried `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` and `sudo update-initramfs -u`, but it has not helped matters. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I believe you need this `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` in your `/etc/default/grub` file to stop verbose output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `verbose output` to stop you need to edit the `/etc/default/grub` file:

1. Open the `/etc/default/grub` file in `nano`:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Look for the line

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT 

   # and add this to it 

   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```
3. Now after editing the file do the following to `save` and `close`:

   - press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>, then <kbd>enter</kbd>
   - finally <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>
4. Update grub by running this in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
5. Reboot and the "verbose output" should be gone

### WARNING

On `step 2`please add to whatever is in the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line **DO NOT REMOVE WHATEVER IS ALREADY THERE**.

Comment: Oops. Umm, what happens if I do remove the stuff that is there? Just wondering whether I irreversibly damaged my computer.

Comment: That you will have to find out.. Unless you know well enough to do so please don't. Most likely "data loss, re-installation"